# What do codes "O", "T", "X", and "N" mean on Wal-Mart receipts?

Tags: united-states, sales-tax, shopping, receipt

What do the four individual Walmart receipt codes of "O", "T", "X", and "N" denote?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about walmart receipts, not personal finance.